# MongoDB returns truncated float value to 6 decimal points

Tags: c, linux, api, mongodb

I connect to a MongoDB with the latest C-Driver. When I insert a float value, say 1.0043820142745972, and then query it back I only seem to get 1.004382! For some reason all float values get truncated to 6 digits past the decimal point.

here's the code that I use to query it back

```
bson_init(query);
bson_append_double(query, "column", value);
bson_finish(query);
```

and when I iterate through the results with `mongo_cursor_next()` I access the value with `bson_iterator_double`.

How can I get the exact value back as it is stored in the database?

Comment: when I use Umongo to browse the collection then I can see the full float value being stored. Just can't retrieve it using the C API. I also tried using PHP and the returned value is still truncated, but this time to 13 decimal points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do get your value back, it's just a matter of print format.

Printing out the value in question to full precision, we see that it's the same value for both representations:

```
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FF 1.0043820142745972
1.00438201427459716796875
Prelude Text.FShow.RealFloat> FF 1.004382
1.00438201427459716796875
```

By default, floating point values are printed with six digits after the decimal point in C, so the value is rounded when you look at it.